# Insert into php input stream (php://input)

Tags: php

I would like to place data into the PHP input stream `php://input`  so that I can return it when I call `file_get_contents("php://input");`.

I am doing this to build a test to confirm the behavior of code I can not alter.

How can I set `php://input`?

Comment: It's all in the manual.  php://input is read-only.  It contains the raw request body.  The only way to influence the contents of php://input is to make a HTTP request that populates the request body with the data you want to present to PHP.  http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have the command that calls the PHP insert the input before calling your command.

perhaps using pipes?

additionally, you can change the existing code so it doesn't read from input, but instead from a parameter like this:

Instead of this:

```
function current_function(){
    $a = file_get_contents("php://input");
    # do stuff with $a
}
```

try this:

```
function do_thing_before_current_function($a){
    $STDIN = file_get_contents("php://input");
    # do stuff to pre-process STDIN
    current_function($STDIN);
}
function current_function($a){
    # do stuff with $a
}
```

This helps making your design more testable.

Also, if you can't alter the code, try piping stuff into the PHP script within your bash shell:

```
$ echo "input_here" | php your_script_name.php
```

or, if on Windows, do this:

```
C:\> \path\to\php.exe \path\to\your_script_name.php < example_input_content.txt
```

Hope that helps!